# Find $E(e^{-\Lambda}|X=1)$ where $\Lambda\sim Exp(1)$ and $P(X=x)=\frac{\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}}{x!}$.

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ have probability mass function
>   $$P_\lambda(X=x)=\frac{\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}}{x!},\quad x=0,1,2,\ldots$$
>   and suppose that $\lambda$ is a realization of a random variable $\Lambda$ with probability distribution function
>   $$f(\lambda)=\begin{cases}e^{-\lambda} &; \lambda>0 \\ 0 &; \lambda\leq 0.\end{cases}$$
>   What is
>   $$E(e^{-\Lambda}|X=1)?$$

I am unsure how to interpret this question. Usually, we have either two discrete random variables $(X,Y)$, or two continuous random variables $(X,Y)$ and I know some techniques to find the conditional expectation $E(X|Y=y)$. But how to do it in general when, as in this case, the random variables are not of the same type?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, these problems are fun. This is a bit of an intro problem to Bayesian methodology. First of all, you need to find the probability density function of $\Lambda \mid X = 1$. By Bayes' Theorem, this is given by
$$\pi_{\Lambda \mid X}(\lambda \mid x = 1) = \dfrac{f_{X \mid \Lambda}(1 \mid \lambda)\pi(\lambda)}{\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f_{X \mid \Lambda}(1 \mid \lambda)\pi(\lambda)\text{ d}\lambda}\text{,}$$
where $\pi$ is the probability density function of your "prior" random variable (i.e., a parameter which is varying - in this case, your $\lambda$. So $\pi(\lambda) = f(\lambda)$ in the context of your problem).

Now $$f_{X \mid \Lambda}(1 \mid \lambda) = P_{\lambda}(X = 1) = \dfrac{\lambda e^{-\lambda}}{1!} = \lambda e^{-\lambda}\text{.}$$
Furthermore, $\pi(\lambda) = e^{-\lambda}$ for $\lambda > 0$, so 
$$f_{X \mid \Lambda}(1 \mid \lambda)\pi(\lambda ) = \lambda e^{-2\lambda}\text{, } \lambda > 0\text{.}$$
So, in this case,
$$\pi_{\Lambda \mid X}(\lambda \mid x = 1) = \dfrac{f_{X \mid \Lambda}(1 \mid \lambda)\pi(\lambda)}{\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f_{X \mid \Lambda}(1 \mid \lambda)\pi(\lambda)\text{ d}\lambda} = c\lambda e^{-2\lambda}\text{, }\lambda > 0$$
where $c = \dfrac{1}{\text{that integral}}$ is just some constant [note that the parameter of interest here is $\lambda$!].

Recall that [one possible parametrization of the Gamma density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Probability_density_function_2) is
$$f(x) = \dfrac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-\beta x}\text{, }x \geq 0\text{, } \alpha, \beta > 0\text{.}$$

Because of the similar form (*and identical support*, i.e., $\Lambda > 0$ and $X > 0$), we can infer that $\Lambda \mid X = 1$ is Gamma distributed with $\alpha = 2$, $\beta = 2$. Furthermore,
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{-\Lambda} \mid X = 1] = \mathbb{E}[e^{(-1)\Lambda} \mid X = 1] = M_{\Lambda \mid X = 1}(-1)$$
where $M_{\Lambda \mid X = 1}$ is the moment-generating function of $\Lambda \mid X = 1$, which is 
$$M_{\Lambda \mid X = 1}(t) = \left(\dfrac{\beta}{\beta - t}\right)^{\alpha}\text{, } t < \beta\text{,}$$
or in this case,
$$M_{\Lambda \mid X = 1}(-1) = \left[\dfrac{2}{2-(-1)}\right]^{2} = \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{2} = \dfrac{4}{9}\text{.}$$

Of course, you could do all of the integration involved in this problem... but I will leave that up to you if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I never saw Bayes rule in the form of your first equation; it was not introduced in the textbook from which this question come (An Introduction to Probability and Statistics, Rohatgi and Saleh). Is there another way of getting the result? Or perhaps this equation has a very simple and elementary proof? The only Bayes rule that I know is $$P(H_k|A)=\frac{P(H_k)P(A|H_k)}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(H_n)P(A|H_n)}$$ for disjoint events $H_n$ such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty H_n=\Omega$.

Comment: @Jordan  That's Bayes' Rule for probability *mass* functions (for discrete random variables).  What Clarinetist showed is simply its extension to probability *density* functions (for continuous RV).  The same base principle is at work. $$f_{H\mid A}(k \mid a) = \dfrac{f_H(k)\;f_{A\mid H}(a\mid k)}{\int_{h\in\Omega} f_H(h)\;f_{A\mid H}(a\mid h)\operatorname d h}$$