# Conditional Expectation and Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume that $X$ has as a probability mass function:

$P_{\lambda}(X=x)=\displaystyle\frac{\lambda^{x}e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$  $x=0,1,2,..$

Now, suppose $\lambda$ is given by a random variable $\Lambda$ whose probability density function is $f(\lambda)=e^{-\lambda}$ for $\lambda$ positive. Compute $E(e^{-\Lambda}|X=1)$.

---

I'm not sure on how to start the problem. I saw a solution given: [Find $E(e^{-\Lambda}|X=1)$ where $\Lambda\sim Exp(1)$ and $P(X=x)=\frac{\lambda^xe^{-\lambda}}{x!}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052015/find-ee-lambdax-1-where-lambda-sim-exp1-and-px-x-frac-lambda), but I haven't seen that form of Bayes' Theorem yet (only the one defined for events in a probability space). Is there a way to do this problem without using that result given? Or is that the only (or quickest) way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For events $A$ with $P(A)>0$, the conditional expectation $\mathrm{E}[Z\mid A]$ is simply $\mathrm{E}[Z\mathbf{1}_A]/P(A)$. Thus,
$$
\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{e}^{-\Lambda}\mid X=1]=\frac{\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{e}^{-\Lambda}\mathbf{1}_{X=1}]}{P(X=1)}.
$$
Now,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{e}^{-\Lambda}\mathbf{1}_{X=1}\mid \Lambda]&=\mathrm{e}^{-\Lambda}\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_{X=1}\mid \Lambda]=\mathrm{e}^{-\Lambda}P_{\Lambda}(X=1)=\Lambda\mathrm{e}^{-2\Lambda}
\end{align}
$$
and hence by the tower property
$$
\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{e}^{-\Lambda}\mathbf{1}_{X=1}]=\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{e}^{-\Lambda}\mathbf{1}_{X=1}\mid\Lambda]]=\mathrm{E}[\Lambda\mathrm{e}^{-2\Lambda}]=\frac19.
$$
Similarly, one sees that $P(X=1)=\frac14$ so that
$$
\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{e}^{-\Lambda}\mid X=1]=\frac49.
$$